# If else statement doesnt work and cant figure out why

Tags: r, if-statement

Can someone explain why my else part of my function doesnt work?

finaltable;

```
Duplicate Digit6  Digit7 Digit7a Digit7b Digit7c Digit7d Dead carried
137401 137401 2017681 2017681 2018047 2018047 2018219    1       0 
137402 137402 2017731 2017731 2017856 2017856 2018279    0       0

w <- function(finaltable){
if (nchar(tail(names(finaltable),1) >= nchar(c("carried")))) {(ncol(finaltable)-2)
    } else (ncol(finaltable)-1)
}
```

I have colnames (Duplicate, digit, dead, carried). I want the last digit column. Depending on the day I will have tail(names(finaltable),1 = carried or dead. If carried, I need to subtract two columns, if dead then one column. However, I have several columns named dead or carried that are associated with number. However, the max dead will be is dead99. Thus I have a max of 6 characters.

I then want to dump my function into below.

```
SubtractROW<-finaltable[paste(ROWS), w(finaltable)];
BarCODEtable<-cbind(ILS,ROWS,SubtractROW);
BarCODEtable;
```

Comment: If you want to find the last column with "Digit" in its column name, you could use `max(which(grepl("^Digit", names(finaltable))))` instead of an if else.

Comment: @beginneR, what does this mean? "^Digit"?

Comment: @Also, can you explain what is wrong with my function?

Comment: That means, check if the column name starts with "Digit" (the ^ is used to say that the string should be found at the beginning).

Comment: Your function seems to work fine. When I run it, it returns 7 - which is correct for the sample data.

Comment: @ beginneR, now drop carried column off the tail. you should have 5 characters. The function then should go over the if part and do else statment, but it doesnt

Comment: When I drop the last column (carried) the function returns 6. Is that right or wrong? (I'm not sure I fully understand the function)

Comment: It should return 7, if you look at the if statment, it states that if x >= Y then do z, else do w. When you drop carried it should do w not z because in this case x < y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your function, corrected so that it returns the right values:

```
w <- function(finaltable){
  if (nchar(tail(names(finaltable),1)) >= nchar("carried")) {
  (ncol(finaltable)-2)
  } else {
    ncol(finaltable)-1
  }
}

w(finaltable)  # if last column is dropped
#[1] 7
```

The problem was in your if statement, where a `)` was at the wrong place. Running your original if statement results in:

```
nchar(tail(names(finaltable),1) >= nchar(c("carried")))
#[1] 4
```

where it should be

```
nchar(tail(names(finaltable),1)) >= nchar("carried")
#[1] FALSE
```

But as commented above, you could more easily use

```
max(which(grepl("^Digit", names(finaltable))))
```

instead.